# Use of undeclared identifier 'kDefaultNative'

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to generate an audio plugin using the ASPIK SDK. I keep hitting the same stumbling block. Every time I build I get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'kDefaultNative'" on this line in the plugingui.h file.

`const PlatformType& platformType = kDefaultNative,`

If I jump to definition of `PlatformType`, I see that the `kDefaultNative` is defined in iplatformcallback.h in VSTGUI.

```
    enum class PlatformType : int32_t {
    kHWND,      // Windows HWND
    kWindowRef, // macOS WindowRef (Carbon)
    kNSView,    // macOS NSView
    kUIView,    // iOS UIView
    kHWNDTopLevel,  // Windows HWDN Top Level (non child)
    kX11EmbedWindowID,  // X11 XID
    kGdkWindow, // GdkWindow
    
    kDefaultNative = -1 
};
```

I have tried to include this file in the plugingui file but I keep getting the error not found.

Comment: Is `pluginui.h` part of your project, or something externally included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kDefaultNative` identifier is one of the values of a [*scoped enumeration*](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1423015134/scoped-class-enums-fundamentals-and-examples) (i.e. it's in a `class enum { ... }`). So, in order to use it, you need to include that class 'scope'.

So, use a line like the following:

```cpp
const PlatformType& platformType = PlatformType::kDefaultNative;
```